# Does pycharm support remote development like Remote Development in vs code

Tags: docker, pycharm

I set up the docker compose file as interpreter in pycharm and it works pretty well. But one problem is that every time I run tests, it will spin up a new container which takes a while. I have used vscode with [Remote Development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) which allows me to do everything in an existing container. This saves me a lot of time. I wonder if pycharm can do something similar.

Comment: What is preventing you from running the container and mounting your project folder into the container using volumes?

Comment: @twoTimesAgnew I'm already doing that. But I cannot connect pycharm to an existing container. Everytime it will start a new container to run tests

Comment: You can change the `docker-compose` command used by PyCharm in the run configuration for a given script. The default is `up`.

Comment: @PavelKarateev can you please give me an example?